# Multiple Value for Custom Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to each ID have 2 `Custom_Column` values.
How can I do that?

Example Table:

```
ID
1
2
3
```

Example Query:

```
SELECT id, (id*2) as Custom_Value, (id*4) as Custom_Value FROM numbers
```

Response:

```
ID    Custom_Value
1     2
1     4
2     4
2     8
3     6
3     12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `UNION`

```
SELECT ID, (ID*2) as CustomVal FROM tableNAme
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, (ID*4) as CustomVal FROM tableNAme
ORDER BY ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53413/3)